# Data from a WordPress custom metadata table can't be deleted

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I have created my own metadata table to store data from my plugin. Almost everything works perfectly.

I can store information in this table. It is also perfectly synced with the wp_posts table. For example, when I delete posts in Admin, both the posts and the data in the metadata table are deleted.

There is just one small issue. Suppose there are some posts in the Trash... If I remove each of them by clicking on "Delete Permanently", the metadata table data are deleted correctly. However, the same doesn't happen when I click on "Empty Trash". Only the post in the wp_post table is deleted, but the data remains in my metadata table.

Here is a snippet of my class that does this:

```
class MyPlugin_Post_Type{
    public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_post_type' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_taxonomy' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_metadata_table' ) );
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );

        add_action( 'wp_insert_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'delete_post', array( $this, 'delete_post' ) );

        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'add_cpt_author' ) );
    }
    (...ommitted code...)

    public function register_metadata_table(){
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->mypluginmeta = $wpdb->prefix . 'mypluginmeta';
    }

    (...ommitted code...)

    public function delete_post( $post_id ){
        if( ! current_user_can( 'delete_posts' ) ){
            return;
        }
        if( get_post_type( $post ) == 'myplugin-cpt' ){
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->delete(
                $wpdb->mypluginmeta,
                array( 'mypluginfield_id' => $post_id ),
                array( '%d' )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is some other action hook related to this empty trash action that I am missing?